# Pandas: best way to replicate df and fill with new values

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have df1:

```
dates = pd.date_range('20170101',periods=20)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,size=(20,3)),index=dates,columns=['foo','bar','see'])
```

I would like to create df2 with the same shape, index and columns.  I often find myself doing something like this:

```
df2= pd.DataFrame(np.ones(shape(df1),index = df1.index,columns =df1.columns)
```

This is less than ideal.  What's the pythonic way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
df2 = df1.copy()
df2[:] = 1 # Or any other value, for the matter
```

The last line is not even necessary if all you want is to preserve the shape and the row/column headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the dataframe method "where" which will allow you to keep data based on condition and preserve the shape/index of the original df.

```
dates = pd.date_range('20170101',periods=20)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,size=(20,3)),index=dates,columns=['foo','bar','see'])

df2= df1.where(df1['foo'] % 2 == 0, 9999)

df2
```